# Which version of ruby is less buggy?

Tags: ruby

I have recently written some complex ruby script that eventually fails with segfaults in random time and in random places, like nokogiri, mechanize, iconv, timeout. I've tried it under 1.9.1 p 129, 1.8.6 p 369 under windows 7 and 1.8.7 under ubuntu, still the same behavior. Since there are three actual versions (1.8.6, 1.8.7 and 1.9.1) to be downloaded from ruby-lang, which one is the less buggy and what is the reason for maintaining all of them?

Well, I'm not sure what is causing errors, here is a sample dump of error

```
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:93: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.1p129 (2009-05-12 revision 23412) [i386-mswin32]

-- control frame ----------
c:0031 p:0167 s:0167 b:0163 l:000162 d:000162 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:93
c:0030 p:0111 s:0155 b:0155 l:000154 d:000154 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2353
c:0029 p:0024 s:0147 b:0147 l:000146 d:000146 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2328
c:0028 p:0099 s:0142 b:0142 l:000141 d:000141 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2288
c:0027 p:0050 s:0136 b:0136 l:000898 d:000898 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/chain/response_reader.rb:15
c:0026 p:0021 s:0128 b:0128 l:000127 d:000127 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/chain.rb:25
c:0025 p:0067 s:0124 b:0124 l:001788 d:000123 BLOCK  D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:490
c:0024 p:0017 s:0120 b:0120 l:000112 d:000119 BLOCK  D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1120
c:0023 p:0038 s:0118 b:0118 l:000117 d:000117 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2251
c:0022 p:0110 s:0113 b:0113 l:000112 d:000112 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1119
c:0021 p:0097 s:0108 b:0108 l:000107 d:000107 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1103
c:0020 p:0513 s:0101 b:0101 l:001788 d:001788 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:485
c:0019 p:0170 s:0075 b:0075 l:000074 d:000074 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:413
c:0018 p:0123 s:0066 b:0066 l:000065 d:000065 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:344
c:0017 p:0024 s:0060 b:0060 l:000059 d:000059 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/form.rb:130
c:0016 p:0039 s:0055 b:0055 l:000054 d:000054 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:340
c:0015 p:0223 s:0050 b:0050 l:000049 d:000049 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:238
c:0014 p:0112 s:0045 b:0045 l:000044 d:000044 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:286
c:0013 p:0330 s:0042 b:0042 l:000041 d:000041 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:115
c:0012 p:0038 s:0033 b:0033 l:000016 d:000032 BLOCK  D:/code/h4/post.rb:22
c:0011 p:---- s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 FINISH
c:0010 p:---- s:0028 b:0028 l:000027 d:000027 CFUNC  :times
c:0009 p:0050 s:0025 b:0025 l:000016 d:000024 BLOCK  D:/code/h4/post.rb:19
c:0008 p:---- s:0022 b:0022 l:000021 d:000021 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 CFUNC  :times
c:0006 p:0111 s:0017 b:0017 l:000016 d:000016 TOP    D:/code/h4/post.rb:14
c:0005 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 CFUNC  :load
c:0003 p:0061 s:0006 b:0006 l:000e84 d:00227c EVAL   -e:1
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000e84 d:000e84 TOP   
---------------------------
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:93: [BUG] object allocation during garbage collection phase
ruby 1.9.1p129 (2009-05-12 revision 23412) [i386-mswin32]

-- control frame ----------
c:0031 p:0167 s:0167 b:0163 l:000162 d:000162 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:93
c:0030 p:0111 s:0155 b:0155 l:000154 d:000154 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2353
c:0029 p:0024 s:0147 b:0147 l:000146 d:000146 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2328
c:0028 p:0099 s:0142 b:0142 l:000141 d:000141 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2288
c:0027 p:0050 s:0136 b:0136 l:000898 d:000898 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/chain/response_reader.rb:15
c:0026 p:0021 s:0128 b:0128 l:000127 d:000127 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/chain.rb:25
c:0025 p:0067 s:0124 b:0124 l:001788 d:000123 BLOCK  D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:490
c:0024 p:0017 s:0120 b:0120 l:000112 d:000119 BLOCK  D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1120
c:0023 p:0038 s:0118 b:0118 l:000117 d:000117 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2251
c:0022 p:0110 s:0113 b:0113 l:000112 d:000112 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1119
c:0021 p:0097 s:0108 b:0108 l:000107 d:000107 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1103
c:0020 p:0513 s:0101 b:0101 l:001788 d:001788 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:485
c:0019 p:0170 s:0075 b:0075 l:000074 d:000074 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:413
c:0018 p:0123 s:0066 b:0066 l:000065 d:000065 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:344
c:0017 p:0024 s:0060 b:0060 l:000059 d:000059 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/form.rb:130
c:0016 p:0039 s:0055 b:0055 l:000054 d:000054 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:340
c:0015 p:0223 s:0050 b:0050 l:000049 d:000049 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:238
c:0014 p:0112 s:0045 b:0045 l:000044 d:000044 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:286
c:0013 p:0330 s:0042 b:0042 l:000041 d:000041 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:115
c:0012 p:0038 s:0033 b:0033 l:000016 d:000032 BLOCK  D:/code/h4/post.rb:22
c:0011 p:---- s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 FINISH
c:0010 p:---- s:0028 b:0028 l:000027 d:000027 CFUNC  :times
c:0009 p:0050 s:0025 b:0025 l:000016 d:000024 BLOCK  D:/code/h4/post.rb:19
c:0008 p:---- s:0022 b:0022 l:000021 d:000021 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 CFUNC  :times
c:0006 p:0111 s:0017 b:0017 l:000016 d:000016 TOP    D:/code/h4/post.rb:14
c:0005 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 CFUNC  :load
c:0003 p:0061 s:0006 b:0006 l:000e84 d:00227c EVAL   -e:1
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000e84 d:000e84 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information-----------------------------------------
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:93:in `read'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2353:in `read_chunked'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2328:in `read_body_0'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2288:in `read_body'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/chain/response_reader.rb:15:in `handle'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/chain.rb:25:in `handle'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:490:in `block in fetch_page'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1120:in `block in transport_request'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2251:in `reading_body'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1119:in `transport_request'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1103:in `request'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:485:in `fetch_page'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:413:in `post_form'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:344:in `submit'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/form.rb:130:in `submit'
D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:340:in `submit'
D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:238:in `register'
D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:286:in `login'
D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:115:in `checkifworks'
D:/code/h4/post.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
D:/code/h4/post.rb:19:in `times'
D:/code/h4/post.rb:19:in `block in <top (required)>'
D:/code/h4/post.rb:14:in `times'
D:/code/h4/post.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'

[NOTE]
You may encounter a bug of Ruby interpreter. Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I'll try to use Jruby in case I get to use nokogiri with it. Here is another dump, if it may somehow be useful

```
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:135: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.1p129 (2009-05-12 revision 23412) [i386-mswin32]

-- control frame ----------
c:0026 p:---- s:0142 b:0142 l:000141 d:000141 CFUNC  :sysread
c:0025 p:0019 s:0138 b:0137 l:000adc d:000136 BLOCK  D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:135
c:0024 p:0103 s:0135 b:0135 l:000e08 d:000e08 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:52
c:0023 p:0026 s:0123 b:0123 l:000122 d:000122 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:82
c:0022 p:0013 s:0117 b:0117 l:000adc d:000adc METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:134
c:0021 p:0025 s:0114 b:0114 l:000113 d:000113 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:116
c:0020 p:0013 s:0108 b:0108 l:000107 d:000107 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:126
c:0019 p:0012 s:0105 b:0105 l:000104 d:000104 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2135
c:0018 p:0013 s:0099 b:0099 l:000098 d:000098 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2124
c:0017 p:0069 s:0091 b:0091 l:000090 d:000090 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1117
c:0016 p:0097 s:0086 b:0086 l:000085 d:000085 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1103
c:0015 p:0513 s:0079 b:0079 l:0025a0 d:0025a0 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:485
c:0014 p:0346 s:0053 b:0053 l:000052 d:000052 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:238
c:0013 p:0016 s:0044 b:0044 l:000043 d:000043 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:185
c:0012 p:0085 s:0040 b:0040 l:000039 d:000039 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:217
c:0011 p:0112 s:0035 b:0035 l:000034 d:000034 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:286
c:0010 p:0308 s:0032 b:0032 l:000031 d:000031 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:115
c:0009 p:0011 s:0023 b:0023 l:000015 d:000022 BLOCK  D:/code/h4/post.rb:14
c:0008 p:---- s:0021 b:0021 l:000020 d:000020 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0019 b:0019 l:000018 d:000018 CFUNC  :times
c:0006 p:0107 s:0016 b:0016 l:000015 d:000015 TOP    D:/code/h4/post.rb:13
c:0005 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 CFUNC  :load
c:0003 p:0061 s:0006 b:0006 l:000604 d:001a54 EVAL   -e:1
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000604 d:000604 TOP   
---------------------------
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:135: [BUG] object allocation during garbage collection phase
ruby 1.9.1p129 (2009-05-12 revision 23412) [i386-mswin32]

-- control frame ----------
c:0026 p:---- s:0142 b:0142 l:000141 d:000141 CFUNC  :sysread
c:0025 p:0019 s:0138 b:0137 l:000adc d:000136 BLOCK  D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:135
c:0024 p:0103 s:0135 b:0135 l:000e08 d:000e08 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:52
c:0023 p:0026 s:0123 b:0123 l:000122 d:000122 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:82
c:0022 p:0013 s:0117 b:0117 l:000adc d:000adc METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:134
c:0021 p:0025 s:0114 b:0114 l:000113 d:000113 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:116
c:0020 p:0013 s:0108 b:0108 l:000107 d:000107 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:126
c:0019 p:0012 s:0105 b:0105 l:000104 d:000104 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2135
c:0018 p:0013 s:0099 b:0099 l:000098 d:000098 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2124
c:0017 p:0069 s:0091 b:0091 l:000090 d:000090 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1117
c:0016 p:0097 s:0086 b:0086 l:000085 d:000085 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1103
c:0015 p:0513 s:0079 b:0079 l:0025a0 d:0025a0 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:485
c:0014 p:0346 s:0053 b:0053 l:000052 d:000052 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:238
c:0013 p:0016 s:0044 b:0044 l:000043 d:000043 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:185
c:0012 p:0085 s:0040 b:0040 l:000039 d:000039 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:217
c:0011 p:0112 s:0035 b:0035 l:000034 d:000034 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:286
c:0010 p:0308 s:0032 b:0032 l:000031 d:000031 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:115
c:0009 p:0011 s:0023 b:0023 l:000015 d:000022 BLOCK  D:/code/h4/post.rb:14
c:0008 p:---- s:0021 b:0021 l:000020 d:000020 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0019 b:0019 l:000018 d:000018 CFUNC  :times
c:0006 p:0107 s:0016 b:0016 l:000015 d:000015 TOP    D:/code/h4/post.rb:13
c:0005 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 CFUNC  :load
c:0003 p:0061 s:0006 b:0006 l:000604 d:001a54 EVAL   -e:1
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000604 d:000604 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information-----------------------------------------
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:135:in `sysread'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:135:in `block in rbuf_fill'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:82:in `timeout'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2135:in `read_status_line'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2124:in `read_new'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1117:in `transport_request'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1103:in `request'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:485:in `fetch_page'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:238:in `get'
D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:185:in `myget'
D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:217:in `register'
D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:286:in `login'
D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:115:in `checkifworks'
D:/code/h4/post.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
D:/code/h4/post.rb:13:in `times'
D:/code/h4/post.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'

[NOTE]
You may encounter a bug of Ruby interpreter. Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

And yet another. I would expect that since I'm not reading any memory directly or making some relatively low-level manipulations the worst thing I can get from Ruby Interpreter must be an Exception? Am I right?

```
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:1078: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.1p129 (2009-05-12 revision 23412) [i386-mswin32]

-- control frame ----------
c:0024 p:---- s:0134 b:0134 l:000133 d:000133 CFUNC  :collect
c:0023 p:0017 s:0131 b:0131 l:000130 d:000130 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:1078
c:0022 p:0052 s:0128 b:0127 l:000126 d:000126 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:1051
c:0021 p:0033 s:0123 b:0123 l:000122 d:000122 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:740
c:0020 p:0555 s:0116 b:0116 l:000115 d:000115 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/chain/uri_resolver.rb:62
c:0019 p:0021 s:0107 b:0107 l:000106 d:000106 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/chain.rb:25
c:0018 p:0251 s:0103 b:0103 l:000102 d:000102 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:457
c:0017 p:0346 s:0077 b:0077 l:000076 d:000076 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:238
c:0016 p:0258 s:0068 b:0068 l:000a74 d:000067 BLOCK  D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:464
c:0015 p:---- s:0052 b:0052 l:000051 d:000051 FINISH
c:0014 p:---- s:0050 b:0050 l:000049 d:000049 CFUNC  :each
c:0013 p:0243 s:0047 b:0047 l:000a74 d:000a74 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:446
c:0012 p:0174 s:0040 b:0040 l:000039 d:000039 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:232
c:0011 p:0112 s:0035 b:0035 l:000034 d:000034 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:286
c:0010 p:0308 s:0032 b:0032 l:000031 d:000031 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:115
c:0009 p:0011 s:0023 b:0023 l:000015 d:000022 BLOCK  D:/code/h4/post.rb:14
c:0008 p:---- s:0021 b:0021 l:000020 d:000020 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0019 b:0019 l:000018 d:000018 CFUNC  :times
c:0006 p:0107 s:0016 b:0016 l:000015 d:000015 TOP    D:/code/h4/post.rb:13
c:0005 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 CFUNC  :load
c:0003 p:0061 s:0006 b:0006 l:0001d4 d:001624 EVAL   -e:1
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:0001d4 d:0001d4 TOP   
---------------------------
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:1078: [BUG] object allocation during garbage collection phase
ruby 1.9.1p129 (2009-05-12 revision 23412) [i386-mswin32]

-- control frame ----------
c:0024 p:---- s:0134 b:0134 l:000133 d:000133 CFUNC  :collect
c:0023 p:0017 s:0131 b:0131 l:000130 d:000130 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:1078
c:0022 p:0052 s:0128 b:0127 l:000126 d:000126 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:1051
c:0021 p:0033 s:0123 b:0123 l:000122 d:000122 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:740
c:0020 p:0555 s:0116 b:0116 l:000115 d:000115 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/chain/uri_resolver.rb:62
c:0019 p:0021 s:0107 b:0107 l:000106 d:000106 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/chain.rb:25
c:0018 p:0251 s:0103 b:0103 l:000102 d:000102 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:457
c:0017 p:0346 s:0077 b:0077 l:000076 d:000076 METHOD D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:238
c:0016 p:0258 s:0068 b:0068 l:000a74 d:000067 BLOCK  D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:464
c:0015 p:---- s:0052 b:0052 l:000051 d:000051 FINISH
c:0014 p:---- s:0050 b:0050 l:000049 d:000049 CFUNC  :each
c:0013 p:0243 s:0047 b:0047 l:000a74 d:000a74 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:446
c:0012 p:0174 s:0040 b:0040 l:000039 d:000039 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:232
c:0011 p:0112 s:0035 b:0035 l:000034 d:000034 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:286
c:0010 p:0308 s:0032 b:0032 l:000031 d:000031 METHOD D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:115
c:0009 p:0011 s:0023 b:0023 l:000015 d:000022 BLOCK  D:/code/h4/post.rb:14
c:0008 p:---- s:0021 b:0021 l:000020 d:000020 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0019 b:0019 l:000018 d:000018 CFUNC  :times
c:0006 p:0107 s:0016 b:0016 l:000015 d:000015 TOP    D:/code/h4/post.rb:13
c:0005 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 CFUNC  :load
c:0003 p:0061 s:0006 b:0006 l:0001d4 d:001624 EVAL   -e:1
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:0001d4 d:0001d4 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information-----------------------------------------
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:1078:in `collect'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:1078:in `component_ary'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:1051:in `=='
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/generic.rb:740:in `merge'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/chain/uri_resolver.rb:62:in `handle'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize/chain.rb:25:in `handle'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:457:in `fetch_page'
D:/ruby-1.9.1/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-0.9.3/lib/www/mechanize.rb:238:in `get'
D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:464:in `block in fillform'
D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:446:in `each'
D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:446:in `fillform'
D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:232:in `register'
D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:286:in `login'
D:/code/h4/www/poster.rb:115:in `checkifworks'
D:/code/h4/post.rb:14:in `block in <top (required)>'
D:/code/h4/post.rb:13:in `times'
D:/code/h4/post.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'

[NOTE]
You may encounter a bug of Ruby interpreter. Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Comment: Are you *sure* it's the Ruby implementation that's buggy and not your complex Ruby script?

Comment: All versions of Ruby are pretty much "stable". You shouldn't encounter many bugs in a healthy environment. Do you have other similar problems on the machine your running your code? To me this looks like a hardware problem, mostly because you say it happens at random times and at random places. Bugs causing segfaults are often repeatable.

Comment: Koraktor, I've tried it on another PC, still the same, I don't get any other errors on any of the pc's

Comment: Thanks for the selection. BTW, one reason I wanted to see it run on jRuby, is because even if it had to run in a test mode with some disabled functionality, at least in jRuby it won't fault. You will get a civilized traceback and the potential to run in powerful debug environments...

Comment: I couldn't use jruby since nokogiri uses native libxml binding and it was a core part of the script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only think of three things, which you have probably already considered. But for the record:

1. Try jRuby, just to see what happens. This may pose some issues with native extensions in all those libraries.
2. Bring this up on a ruby forum.
3. Bite the bullet, compile ruby with -g, and debug the C code. If you fix it I will send you a bottle of central coast wine, if that's legal...

Answer (score 2):

1.8.6 was the current version for a long time. 1.9 is the latest version, though it introduced a few incompatibilities with older Ruby programs. 1.8.7 was released as a kind of "bridge" between 1.8 and 1.9, incorporating some newer backward-compatible features but keeping the old interpreter rather than the new YARV virtual machine.

As for "less buggy," I don't really know how to answer that. I haven't encountered a lot of bugs in any version of Ruby itself. The only one I can recall getting bit by a bug is 1.8.6, but that was years ago. What makes you certain that the bugs are in Ruby and not the libraries you were using it with? You say you encountered bugs in three different versions, so it might be reasonable to look at the other code involved.

Comment: In my experience problems like this tend to be located at one of three levels: in ascending order of likelihood: the language, the libraries, the developer's own code. I have seen the first maybe once, the second a few times and the third every day for 30 years. I know which one I'm betting on... :-)

Comment: Pure Ruby code should not ever segfault — if it does, that's evidence of deeper bug — so unless he's creating C extensions, it seems most likely to me that his libraries aren't set up right.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby crashing and burning like this isn't much of a problem to me. You get an error, you google about it, ask Stack Overflow, or use some other gem, or do something different. The main thing I worry about is the language giving you incorrect information - for example, splitting a string incorrectly.

I've found that JRuby and Rubinius have been guilty of the mistaken information kind of bugs, but I've never encountered MRI or YARV doing that. Rubinius examples: [505](https://github.com/evanphx/rubinius/issues/505) and [513](https://github.com/evanphx/rubinius/issues/513), and a JRuby example is [5461](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5641).

I've been working on the [Small Eigen Collider](https://github.com/agrimm/small_eigen_collider) to detect inconsistencies and segfaults in the different implementations.

Answer (score -1):

For me the best solution was: switching to Linux :). After that, all my problems, magically, were solved!

Of course this is not an answer, but may be a solution.

Comment: Without meaning to be impolite, was it more a matter of switching away from Windows?

Comment: "I've tried it ... 1.8.7 under ubuntu, still the same behavior"

Comment: -1 is actually from me, the reason is that I've said in the original question that I've tried Ubuntu and it didn't work