# How to implement cookie support in ruby net/http?

Tags: ruby, cookies

I'd like to add cookie support to a ruby class utilizing net/http to browse the web. Cookies have to be stored in a file to survive after the script has ended. Of course I can read the specs and write some kind of a handler, use some cookie.txt format and so on, but it seems to mean reinventing the wheel. Is there a better way to accomplish this task? Maybe some kind of a cooie jar class to take care of cookies?

Comment: I've used mechanize originally, check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448100/which-version-of-ruby-is-less-buggy bounty is still active)

Comment: i know this isn't a real answer but I was beating my head against this problem for a while and finally tried `rest-client` and it worked immediately. I didn't need to manually handle cookies at all.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Taken from [DZone Snippets](https://web.archive.org/web/20090221141735/http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/788)

```
http = Net::HTTP.new('profil.wp.pl', 443)
http.use_ssl = true
path = '/login.html'

# GET request -> so the host can set his cookies
resp, data = http.get(path, nil)
cookie = resp.response['set-cookie'].split('; ')[0]


# POST request -> logging in
data = 'serwis=wp.pl&url=profil.html&tryLogin=1&countTest=1&logowaniessl=1&login_username=blah&login_password=blah'
headers = {
  'Cookie' => cookie,
  'Referer' => 'http://profil.wp.pl/login.html',
  'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

resp, data = http.post(path, data, headers)


# Output on the screen -> we should get either a 302 redirect (after a successful login) or an error page
puts 'Code = ' + resp.code
puts 'Message = ' + resp.message
resp.each {|key, val| puts key + ' = ' + val}
puts data
```

**update**

```
#To save the cookies, you can use PStore
cookies = PStore.new("cookies.pstore")

# Save the cookie  
cookies.transaction do
  cookies[:some_identifier] = cookie
end

# Retrieve the cookie back
cookies.transaction do
  cookie = cookies[:some_identifier] 
end
```

Comment: >> "Cookies have to be stored in a file to survive after the script has ended"

Comment: -1: the format for cookies given by the server's 'set-cookie' header is *not* the same as the format for cookies sent by the client in the 'cooki' header.  Note the different role of semicolons in sections 4.2.2 and 4.3.4 of [RFC2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt).  The "cookie-av" parts of the set-cookie header need to be stripped out, else you risk losing part of your cookie when sending it to the server.

Comment: Update to use PStore for storing the cookies

Comment: Fixed the issue raised by rampion

Comment: but why .split('; ')[0] ?

Comment: If there were multiple cookies sent, resp.response['set-cookie'] returns them in one string with the cookie info separated by "; ", so the split creates an array of cookies.  The [0] part -- I can only assume -- means they are only going to use the first cookie returned by resp.response['set-cookie'].  The answer by mamills uses response.get_fields('set-cookie'), which is more accurate in finding the cookie values.

Answer (score 46):

The accepted answer will not work if your server returns and expects multiple cookies.  This could happen, for example, if the server returns a set of FedAuth[n] cookies.  If this affects you, you might want to look into using something along the lines of the following instead:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new('https://example.com', 443)
http.use_ssl = true
path1 = '/index.html'
path2 = '/index2.html'

# make a request to get the server's cookies
response = http.get(path)
if (response.code == '200')
    all_cookies = response.get_fields('set-cookie')
    cookies_array = Array.new
    all_cookies.each { | cookie |
        cookies_array.push(cookie.split('; ')[0])
    }
    cookies = cookies_array.join('; ')

    # now make a request using the cookies
    response = http.get(path2, { 'Cookie' => cookies })
end
```

Comment: Oh, just posted my answer and then realized this is doing the same as my code just across more lines of code. Voted up for fairness :)

Comment: no, except for ssl things, your example is far better because it is readable.
the 'i-can-write-this-in-one-line' approach is for exercises or jquery masters, i believe it has nothing to do with stackoverflow.

Comment: You can have 'set-cookie' headers in responses which are not code 200 by the way. That code would miss those.

Comment: Excellent!! Your answer save my life.. :-) Can you redirect me to some resources, from where you got these information.

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer does not work. You need to access the internal representation of the response header where the multiple set-cookie values are stores separately and then remove everything after the first semicolon from these string and join them together. Here is code that works

```
r = http.get(path)
cookie = {'Cookie'=>r.to_hash['set-cookie'].collect{|ea|ea[/^.*?;/]}.join}
r = http.get(next_path,cookie)
```

Comment: `to_hash[set-cookie]` maybe `nil`. You can use `to_hash['set-cookie']&.collect` on modern Ruby to deal with it.

Comment: Good catch, which version of Ruby is that?

Comment: `&.`, the Safe Navigation Operator, was introduced in Ruby 2.3.0.

Answer (score 10):

Use [http-cookie](https://github.com/sparklemotion/http-cookie), which implements RFC-compliant parsing and rendering, plus a jar.

A crude example that happens to follow a redirect post-login:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'http-cookie'

uri = URI('...')
jar = HTTP::CookieJar.new

Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, use_ssl: uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri
  req.form_data = { ... }
  res = http.request req
  res.get_fields('Set-Cookie').each do |value|
    jar.parse(value, req.uri)
  end

  fail unless res.code == '302'

  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri + res['Location'])
  req['Cookie'] = HTTP::Cookie.cookie_value(jar.cookies(uri))
  res = http.request req
end
```

Why do this? Because the answers above are incredibly insufficient and flat out don't work in many RFC-compliant scenarios (happened to me), so relying on the very lib implementing just what's needed is infinitely more robust if you want to handle more than one particular case.

Comment: Where is jar defined?

Answer (score 3):

I've used Curb and Mechanize for a similar project.
Just enable cookies support and save the cookies to a temp cookiejar...
If your using net/http or packages without cookie support built in, you will need to write your own cookie handling.

Comment: I'm on windows where curb won't install :(

Answer (score 1):

You can send receive cookies using headers.

You can store the header in any persistence framework.  Whether it is some sort of database, or files.