# How to implement cookies in Ruby Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby, http, cookies, net-library

That's my code.

Now I need to SEND a cookie to the host but I can't find a solution.

---

```
def get_network_file(url=nil)
  begin
    http = Net::HTTP.new( @service_server, 80 )
    resp, data = http.get( url, { "Accept-Language" => @locale } )
    if resp.code.to_i != 200
      RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.error "*** return code != 200. code = #{resp.code}"
      return ""
    end
    rescue Exception => exc
      RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.error "*** message --> #{exc.message}"
      return ""
    end
    return data
  end
end
```

---

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement cookie support in ruby net/http?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486703/how-to-implement-cookie-support-in-ruby-net-http)

Answer (score 5):

You pass cookies via the same hash you're sending the "Accept-Language" header, something like:

```
resp, data = http.get( url, { 
     "Accept-Language" => @locale, 
     "Cookie" => "YOUR_COOKIE" 
} )
```

Odds are you'll need to capture the cookie first, though.  See [this](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/788) for examples of cookie handling.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first retrieve the cookie(s) from your server from the server's response's "set-cookie" header field(s).  After you've retrieved the cookie(s) then you pass it/them in your client's request's "cookie" header.

This question is asked already at [How to implement cookie support in ruby net/http?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1486703)

The accepted answer there is fine unless your server returns a set of cookies in which case you may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9320190/1024480