# How to check if google user has already made an account with my site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, access-token

In my site users are able to sign-up with their google accounts. I am able to do that just fine and I store their access token and when the access token expires. Also I get a new token if their previous access token once it expired. I want to be able to automatically login users if they are already logged in with the google account they signed up with. Is that even possible? I am using the omniauth-google-oauth2 and google-ruby-api-client because I want to use google docs and google calendar in the future.

here is how I handle the saving and registration of the user.

```
def self.find_for_google_oauth2(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
      data = access_token.info
      user = User.where(:email => data["email"]).first

      unless user
          user = User.create(name: data["name"],
                   email: data["email"],
                   password: Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
                   access_token: access_token.credentials.token,
                   expiredate: DateTime.now + (access_token.credentials.expires_at/1000).seconds,
                   expires: access_token.credentials.expires
                  )
      end

      if (user.expires && (DateTime.now > user.expiredate))
        user.access_token = access_token.credentials.token
        user.expiredate = DateTime.now + (access_token.credentials.expires_at/1000).seconds
        user.expires = access_token.credentials.expires
      end

      user
  end
```

Comment: Where do you get `access_token` to pass to that method? Why do you check for token expiration yourselves, instead of letting google to do that for you? I would suggest you to simply store the `access_token` in user’s cookies (pure security) or invent your own authentication procedure so that user will log in within her cookies to your site, you’ll check the credentials, lookup a token in your database and silently perform `oauth` within google services.

Comment: I get it from the omniauth-google-oauth2 gem. It gives me the time(in milliseconds) and i turn it into a date. Once expired I renew the token. How do I store it into cookies? Is there a good tutorial to make it like you say?

Comment: There are [plenty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486703/how-to-implement-cookie-support-in-ruby-net-http). `Net::HTTP` would be sufficient, I guess. Hope it helps.