# How to re-use net:http session +Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, net-http

Scenario:

I am trying to do Net::Http a URL which brings me data (product's list).
In order to fetch the products, I need to firstly set the vehicle for fetching the related data.
(i.e. if no vehicle is set, it brings all the products of that category, but if the vehicle is set, then products result comes according to the vehicle)

So, I am planning firstly to land on the URL which sets the vehicle and then the other URL (category of product which is battery for now) where I'll get the products which are compatible for that vehicle only.

Questions:

Is there any way with that I can use the session created by first URL (which sets the vehicle) and then fetch data only for the vehicle which has been set by previous call?

[URL to set the vehicle](https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/web/AjaxManageMyGarageCmd?vehicleID=450434&vehicleDesc=2010%20Audi%20A3%202.0L%201984CC%20L4%20FI%20Turbo%20VIN&vehicleCODE=1444777&storeId=10151&catalogId=10051&langId=-1&fromCheckFit=false&fromHeader=true&actionCode=addVehicle)

[URL of category battery](https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/c3/car-batteries/15597)

I have tried what Net::Http doc says, used `.start` as well as `.new` but still getting all products rather than vehicle specific.

[https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-How+to+use+Net-3A-3AHTTP](https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/web/AjaxManageMyGarageCmd?vehicleID=450434&vehicleDesc=2010%20Audi%20A3%202.0L%201984CC%20L4%20FI%20Turbo%20VIN&vehicleCODE=1444777&storeId=10151&catalogId=10051&langId=-1&fromCheckFit=false&fromHeader=true&actionCode=addVehicle)

As per the Net::Http doc 
`If you wish to re-use a connection across multiple HTTP requests without automatically closing it you can use ::new instead of ::start.`

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance (fingers crossed).

Comment: Net::HTTP does not support cookies. Which is probally used for storing those values. You can [implement cookies on your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486703/how-to-implement-cookie-support-in-ruby-net-http) or you can use a more advanced [HTTP client like HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) which implements cookies.

Comment: @max Thank you for your input, can you please tell me how HTTParty can help in my scenario?

Comment: Unless you work for Advance Auto Parts, now would be a good time to review the site's [Terms and Conditions](https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/o/termscond).